# My import for products images doesn't show the one from server, but old ones - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, cache

I made an import with new images and now the images that are located in `public/pub/media/import` are the correct ones, so the import was succesfull. But in site are displayed the old ones. I applied the command for reindex, also cleared the cache and flush from terminal.
I also flush catalog images cache from backend on `System -> Cache Management -> Additional Cache Management` but still not working and shows the old images.

What should I do to see the images that are uploaded in import folder, and not the old ones, that don't exist anymore, maybe cached somewhere.